# Automating PayPal monthly statements retrieval

Tags: api, paypal

Is there a way to retrieve the monthly statement pdf files via the PayPal API? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get those particular statements via API, but you can get other reports programmatically via SFTP.  For more information on that, please go to https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ and search for 'sftp'. There you will find articles on how to set it up on your account.